# How to render a PNG-file on the screen with SDL?

Tags: c++, gui, sdl2

I'm coding a 2D platformer in using C++ and SDL2. I've started by coding the GUI, however I'm unsure how to get the menu buttons onto the screen and in the right positions.

How do I load the PNG menu buttons onto the screen in a way that I can adjust them to get them in the right spots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to load your image as a surface and convert the surface into a texture:

```
SDL_Surface* surface = IMG_Load("Path/To/Your/Image.png"); 
SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface); 
SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
```

Then, all you need to do is call [`SDL_RenderCopy`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderCopy) with the destination rect adjusted accordingly. You most likely want to render the whole image unless you're creating a spritesheet.

```
SDL_Rect destination;
destination.x = xPos;
destination.y = yPos;
destination.w = yourImageWidth;
destination.w = yourImageHeight;

SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, &destination);
```

If you need a dynamic way to get the image size, look into [`SDL_QueryTexture`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_QueryTexture) or get the size from the surface before destroying it.

Now, for a GUI system you probably want to wrap all this into a reusable class. Something like the following should allow you to nicely reposition the buttons, and later on add functionality to them.

```
class GuiElement
{
public:
    GuiElement(const std::string& path)
    {
        SDL_Surface* surface = IMG_Load(path.c_str()); 
        m_Texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface); 

        m_Destination.w = surface->w;
        m_Destination.h = surface->h;
        SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
    }
    ~GuiElement()
    {
        SDL_DestroyTexture(m_Texture);
    }

    void Render(SDL_Renderer* renderer)
    {
        m_Destination.x = m_Position.x;
        m_Destination.y = m_Position.y;

        SD_RenderCopy(renderer, m_Texture, NULL, &m_Destination);
    }

    Vec2 m_Position;
protected:
private:
    SDL_Rect m_Destination;
    SDL_Texture* m_Texture;
}
```

I recommend picking up a basic SDL tutorial for stuff like this. They go into a lot more detail about this. [LazyFoo](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/07_texture_loading_and_rendering/index.php)'s tutorial seems to be quite popular.

Comment: Just out of curiosity what would you put in destination.x & destination.y to make the image appear in the center of the screen?

Comment: @ciaranwickham X would be `ScreenWidth / 2.0f - ImageWidth / 2.0f`. Y similarly. (Assuming that you want the *center* of your image at the center)